# Are nonclustered indexes used when joining tables?

Tags: sql-server, index, optimization, nonclustered-index, query-performance

I know that joins of type Sort-Merge don't use nonclustered indexes, because they work by sorting both tables and then joining them.

But I've read recommendations to noncluster index all FKs, I believe that's for helping joining.

Is there then some type of join that uses nonclustered indexes?

Comment: If the nonclustered index is a covering index, then I believe that it would be a good candidate for a Sort-Merge, since the index, itself is sorted and there's no need to access the data pages of the table.

Comment: Oh, also, Paul White has [an interesting article](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation) on the Merge Join.  It might help you visualize the inner workings of the join.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the query execution plan, that should tell you if it is using an index.

I don't know why a sort join couldn't use an index, keys can be read from the index and then sorted if required, which saves scanning the table.

Comment: Sorry, I meant nonclustered indexes. The Custered index is used, not nonclustered ones.

Answer (score 2):

I would put an index on the foreign key ( foreign keys don't automatically have an index  created) and check out Kimberley Tripps article below.
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/when-did-sql-server-stop-putting-indexes-on-foreign-key-columns/